# Emacs - two columns of text in one buffer (source column/comment column)

Tags: emacs

I would like to use Emacs to edit two columns of text side by side in one buffer with one column for source and another for comments, something like this.

```
int main() {    | Comment line 1
   print...     | Comment line 2
}               | Comment line 3
```

Automatic width correction would be nice too. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe [two-column mode](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Two_002dColumn.html) does what you want, though it's a little tricky to use.

Move your cursor to the point just before the `|` and type <kbd>C-x 6 s</kbd>, which should split into two buffers where you want.  And when you're done type <kbd>C-x 6 1</kbd>.

Comment: This is the simple most understanding of how to use two-column mode.

Answer (score 6):

The command `comment-dwim`(<kbd>M-;</kbd>) should do what you want.